# updating the list which is inside the map

Tags: java, list, dictionary

case 1:

```
System.out.print("\n ID: ");
id=scn1.next();
System.out.print("\n Name: ");
name=scn1.next();
System.out.print("\n Department: ");
department=scn1.next();
System.out.print("\n Salary: ");
salary=scn1.next();
Employee emp=new Employee(id,name,department,salary);
listForFinance.add(emp);
m.put("id",listForFinance);
System.out.println("Details added succesfully");
break;
```

the above function is for adding into the list... but how to update it??want to be replaced by the new values with the help of the 'id'

Comment: The code you've posted is pretty irrelevant. You need to state what `listForFinance` is, state what it is you're trying to achieve, and show that you've done some Googling around the problem, what you've found out and why it doesn't work- often this step answers the question for you before you post.

Comment: Bro,i want to update employee details using hashMap..Where iam using ID as a key and name,department,salary as values.Iam putting all the values in a arraylist... Iam able to pass the details but not able to update it.So please help me out in finding the answer..

Answer (score 0):

The question is rather unclear, but i guess/hope this answers the question:
If you want to expand the list that is stored at "id" in `m`, just retrieve the list stored at `m` and insert it there.

So instead of:

```
listForFinance.add(emp);
m.put("id",listForFinance);

if(m.containsKey("id))
    m.get("id").add(emp);
else
{
    ArrayList<EmployeeType> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(emp);
    m.put("id" , list);
}
```

This works since java handles objects by reference.